# SQL Count gives 1 1 instead of 2

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my SQL Query

```
    $sql = "SELECT *, COUNT(seen)
            FROM usr_details 
            WHERE seen=0 AND UserID=3 
            GROUP BY UserID";

    $unread = mysqli_query($DB, $sql);
    $NumberUnread = mysqli_num_rows ($unread);

    echo $NumberUnread;
```

This is the fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc3f08/20/0

Instead of outputing **2** it outputs 1 1
How can I solve this?

Comment: When I use that on my actual code, it displays 1 1 not 2

Comment: Your question is not clear, as per your query it works perfectly

Comment: It does output 2 when I run your sqlfiddle example.

Comment: Yes, the fiddle displays correct info, but when I try it on my actual project, the display is 1 1 instead of 2

Comment: What else haven’t you told us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your problem is on `GROUP BY`

When you use Group by you need to give the field clear.

```
SELECT det_id,usr_id,COUNT(seen) 
FROM user_details 
WHERE seen=0 AND usr_id=3
GROUP BY det_id,usr_id
```

Comment: How would this make a difference when usr_id is also in the where clause?

Comment: Works Great! Thanks @Joakim

Comment: I must have forgotten to put the det_id in group. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @GeorgeLemery I am glad  can help you :)